# Android app not "designed for tablets" due to drawables

Tags: android, google-play, android-drawable, tablet

Google Play states that my app is not designed for tablets: "Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet screen densities."  It links to [4. Use assets designed for tablet screens](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#use-tablet-icons) on the Tablet app quality page.  I'm trying to understand how I'm not compliant with section 4, and I'd appreciate insights.

1. Is section 4 on tablet assets even accurate for Action Bar icon sizes?  It looks like 32dp is the specified size (32x32px at mdpi), but that appears to conflict with the [material touch target size specification](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size), which specifies 24dp.  I use 24dp assets from the [Google material-design-icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) suite for my Action Bar (Toolbar), and there is no such thing as a 32dp Android icon in the suite.
2. I have included `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi`, and `drawable-xxxhdpi` PNG drawable assets in my project, but I have not included `drawable-hdpi` assets.  Could this be the reason why I'm not "designed for tablets?"  The documentation states that all drawables should be "optimized for at least one" of hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, or xxxhdpi sizes, and I have done this for at least one.
3. My launcher icon sizes are correct and include mdpi - xxxhdpi versions (`mipmap-mdpi`, `mipmap-hdpi`, etc.).

Comment: any luck with getting this sorted out? I am facing same issue but for an app created with Unity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this, I submitted the [Design for Tablet Contact Form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/tabletq), which you can use to let Google know why you believe your app is designed for tablets (even though it is not labeled as such).  Google reviewed my submission and agreed, and the app is now labeled as designed for tablets.

Before submitting the form, you should make sure that your app meets the [Tablet App Quality Checklist](https://developer.android.com/develop/quality-guidelines/tablet-app-quality.html) first.

Comment: `your app meets the Tablet App Quality Checklist first.` well to meet that checklist you again should still add all drawable folder but you didn't (in you case you didn't add drawable-hdpi assets)? it makes no sense

Comment: great answer; no need to struggle with any other details (if your app works well on tablets indeed).