# Flutter: How to include customised drawable assets for common tablet screen densities

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-drawable

My amazing app appears to be NOT designed for tablets according to google. Goggle says the problem is that I do not have right asset for tablets:

> Your APK should include customised drawable assets for common tablet
>   screen densities

Here is my project folders where I have all my icons. To be honest there may be some redundant file there however it work fine for the phone
[image]
[image]
Do you guys knows what I should do? should I add new file to the existing folders? or do I need to add file in separate folder? which file should I add? Here is the google guidelines

[image]

many thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android app not "designed for tablets" due to drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409714/android-app-not-designed-for-tablets-due-to-drawables)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the link. I have seen this and I did not believe the answer is raise an appeal but I actually use the form and google came back to me in 1 day saying my app now is designed for tablet... Not sure why but it worked